# How to send a specific data from a multidimensional array in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this

```
"user1@email.com" => array:2 [
    0 => {
        "product": "Product 1",
        "category": "Paint"
    },
    1 => {
        "product": "Product 2",
        "category": "Brushes"
    }
]
"user2@email.com" => array:1 [
    0 => {
        "product" => "Product 3",
        "category" => "Canves"
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is email the user only the info that is part of their array. For example: I would like to email user1@email.com
only these items

```
0 => {
    "product": "Product 1",
    "category": "Paint"
},
1 => {
    "product": "Product 2",
    "category": "Brushes"
}
```

and email user2@email.com

```
0 => {
    "product" => "Product 3",
    "category" => "Canves"
}
```

I've managed to grab the emails by doing this

```
$keys = array_keys($array);

foreach($keys as $key)
{
    if($key != "")
    {
        Mail::to($key)->send(new ProductsEmail($array));
    }
}
```

but I'm having a problem on only getting and sending the info that belongs to that email address.

Comment: in your foreach, you need to declare key/value `foreach($keys as $key => $value)` and use the $value for the mailing `Mail::to($key)->send(new ProductsEmail($value));`

Answer (score 0):

```php
$array = [
    "user1@email.com" => [
        0 => {
            "product" => "Product 1",
            "category" => "Paint"
        },
        1 => {
            "product" => "Product 2",
            "category" => "Brushes"
        }
    ],
    "user2@email.com" => [
        0 => {
            "product" => "Product 3",
            "category" => "Canves"
        }
    ]
];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $emailAddress = $key;
    $items = $value;

    echo '<div style="margin-bottom:20px;">'.$emailAddress.' has purchased :<br/>';

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo '- Product <strong>'.$item->product.'</strong> in category <strong>'.$item->category.'</strong><br/>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer promotes bad practices, like inline HTML, inline styling

Comment: @OsDev this is just an example on where to extract the informations not the actual answer, OP wanted to mail the data.

Comment: He already has a view to parse the data, he only needed the array data

Comment: No, he is having issue getting the data for the specific mail not all of it, so i say it's an issue with getting the right data. @OsDev

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have the value in an array. Please follow this.

```
$temp = ['user1@email.com' => [ ['product'=> 'Product 1', 'category'=>'Paint'], ['product'=> 'Product 2', 'category'=>'Brushes']  ], 'user2@email.com' => [["product" => "Product 3", "category" => "Canves"]]];
$array = json_decode(json_encode($temp, true),true); // convert into multidimensional array 

foreach($array as $email => $products) {

    // please check this and change if required.
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($products); 
    Mail::to($email)->send(new ProductsEmail($products));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This would have to do it, you want to access the values of the email key

```php
foreach ($array as $email => $products) {
    Mail::to($email)->send(new ProductsEmail($products));
}
```